# what is a HTTP response code variant in Panels 3 Drupal

Tags: drupal-panels

Dear Friends.I am using Panels 3 in drupal 6.2.
While creating page panel i get the option variant type where i can either select panel or HTTP response Code.
My query is what is this HTTP response code option for.I tried to add a panel using this option but nothing seems like working.Please help me.

Thanks and Regars

Answer (score 3):

Creating a page variant using a HTTP Response code allows you to redirect the display for the intended path to a 404 page not found, 403 Access denied, or 301 redirect. You would use the first two to keep a user from accessing a specific site display page or you could redirect them to another page that you choose.

If it is not working, check the defined path for the page definition, the position of the variant in the list (panels will display the first variant that meets the criteria), or the contexts you are applying to the page